# Chrome: inconsistent border-width on objects with opacity

Tags: css, google-chrome, border

When opacity is applied to an object with a border, it seems like Chrome is inconsistently rendering the border-with. This problem is especially obvious with borders of 1px and occurs when the border lies between pixels. If opacity is not applied, however, Chrome consistently renders the border.

```css
.btn {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 12px 24px;
    cursor: pointer;
    font: sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    background-color: transparent;
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
    border: 1px solid currentColor;
    border-radius: 3px;
}

.opacity {
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

```html
<div style="margin-bottom: 4px">
  <button class="btn">button</button>
  <button class="btn">button</button>
  <button class="btn">button</button>
</div>
<div>
  <button class="btn opacity">button</button>
  <button class="btn opacity">button</button>
  <button class="btn opacity">button</button>
</div>
```

It depends a little bit on your zoom level etc., but you should be able to see inconsistent border-widths in the second row of buttons. The issue is Chrome specific, I was not able to reproduce it with Safari.

**Question:** Do you know any handy css property that could help with this issue?

**Edit:** Here is a zoomed in screenshot
[image]

Comment: I can’t see anything wrong at any zoom level. Are you using an old version of Chrome?

Comment: Version 65.0.3325.181 on Mac. I probably should also add a screenshot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a little bit of experimentation I found a workaround by adding `transform: translateZ(0);` to the element with opacity. I don't know exactly why this works, but I believe it has to do with the different way Chrome handles animation, and with `transform` Chrome assumes an animation.

```css
.btn {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 12px 24px;
    cursor: pointer;
    font: sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    background-color: transparent;
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
    border: 1px solid currentColor;
    border-radius: 3px;
}

.opacity {
  opacity: 0.5;
  transform: translateZ(0);
}
```

```html
<div style="margin-bottom: 4px">
  <button class="btn">button</button>
  <button class="btn">button</button>
  <button class="btn">button</button>
</div>
<div>
  <button class="btn opacity">button</button>
  <button class="btn opacity">button</button>
  <button class="btn opacity">button</button>
</div>
```

Comment: when doing this you enable the GPU acceleration : https://www.google.com/search?q=translatez(0)+site:stackoverflow.com&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwis8_XqjKTaAhVP26QKHURcBu8QrQIIMSgEMAA&biw=1600&bih=745

Comment: That's right, so I hope someone has a better answer

Comment: no i don't think so, this is the only way i guess ... as it doesn't depend on CSS but on the browser rendring ... the CPU alone is weak so by enabling the GPU you get better rendering